# How to redeclare parent method in a subclass?

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract `Vehicle` class that has abstract `Wheel`s. I know that all subclasses of `Vehicle` will compute their `_wheels` in the same way, so to avoid duplication, I write the implementation in the base class:

```
abstract class Vehicle {
  abstract _wheels: Wheel[];
  wheels() {
    return this._wheels; // assume it's more complex than this
  }
}

abstract class Wheel {}
```

Then I create a specific subclass:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
  _wheels: CarWheel[];
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._wheels = [];
  }
}

class CarWheel extends Wheel {
  hubcap = new CarWheelHubcap()
}
class CarWheelHubcap {}
```

It doesn't have `Wheel`s but `CarWheel`s with a `CarWheelHubcap`. When it's time to enumerate them however, I run into a problem:

```
const car = new Car();
car.wheels().forEach(wheel => wheel.hubcap);
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: Property 'hubcap' does not exist on type 'Wheel'.
```

I would expect this *not* to happen since we've already re-declared `_wheels` as `CarWheel[]`. My guess is it goes up the prototype chain, finds `Vehicle.prototype.wheels` and concludes its return type is `Wheel` (?)

#### Question

Is it possible to fix this without re-implementing `wheels()` method in `Car` class? Once again, the subclasses will all share `Vehicle.prototype.wheels` so it'd be wasteful to re-write

```
wheels() {
  return super.wheels() as CarWheel[];
}
```

in each subclass.

#### Follow-up question

[Modified playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqAWBTRIA8AVAao+BLUi0iAHgC6IB2AJjNngQHzQDeAsAFDTTAD2FEpAE4BXYKR6CAFAAdBPcmMRVoAfQBuOfCEQAuaFk0EAlCwC+Hc+w4B6a9ABiwwaSSCAthMQAaaLgBm0C6IgoS4MAAGALzQdFqI4dBg1NBRcEgoCVSIfmDCIKQwuBTQAEby8F42dgDuhADmiKR64egAntKE0mCCYG6NwdAA5OgIyCCD0PCQidy4gsB53dBZOXmkAHThHKCQtIbaGKMoRGSUNGljTGycqtXpIBB6I-cA2gC60NHvANwcXA2kaB3MYQSQma5cLghUhOYouMLrFTAlAQb7QWyJKDCPq+UiDGAeELcHhuaTaYiBKZwvAQP7QSyWbbgKDQADC3SOIAAEsISsAwNIWPSOEzdmyOfcTuRqDBOSw6fBefzBdEKIhquLBJyeXyBWDfuxGewdiz2YIpWc9vQDmbOQxmMKrMa+AJuEtVerNfqRcbuutkQ86es3HqA58mAH1orddIjEG-BIAKJgYDwSS8fg8bTrEA8OpGA1AA)

Comment: When you do a `const car = new Car();` what exactly `_wheels` is supposed to contain?

Comment: @atiyar I skipped initialization to keep the post short. The important point is that `_wheels` is of type `CarWheel` not `Wheel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample code,

```
class CarWheelHubcap { }

class CarWheel extends Wheel {
  hubcap = new CarWheelHubcap();
}
```

and continuing on to where you encounter the error,

```
const car = new Car();
car.wheels().forEach(wheel => wheel.hubcap);

Error: Property 'hubcap' does not exist on type 'Wheel'.
```

As the error says, `Wheel` does not define a member named `hubcap`.

Your approach of trying to redeclare, that is to say shadow, the `_wheels` property in `Car` with a more specific type has numerous problems. For one, it is not type safe because arrays are mutable. For another, the actual error stems from the return type of the `wheels()` method being inferred from the type of the property `_wheels` in the `Vehicle` class, leaving you in a pickle of writing extra, pointless code or writing complex computed type annotations that aren't necessary for this relatively simple situation.

Instead we will leverage [Parametric Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism). This concept is exposed in TypeScript as Generics and you
can read about them in the [TypeScript: Handbook - Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) section.

It seems that you want to express that `Car` in inheriting from `Vehicle.prototype`, indeed has wheels, but that they are not merely `Wheel`s but `CarWheel`s. Inheritance isn't sufficient to express such a biaxial relationship, we need to use generics to express and enforce that relationship.

**Let's take an initial stab:**

```
class Vehicle<TWheel extends Wheel> {
  abstract _wheels: TWheel[];
  wheels() {
    return this._wheels; // assume it's more complex than this
  }
}
```

What we've done is parameterize `Vehicle` with a type parameter, `TWheel` that specifies what wheels it will have. Furthermore, we have stipulated that any type argument provided for the type parameter `TWheel` must extend `Wheel`.

Now in defining `Car`, we must pass a type argument for `TWheel`

```
class Car extends Vehicle<CarWheel> {
  _wheels: CarWheel[] = [];
}
```

*Note: I removed the redundant empty constructor, replacing it with a field initializer. This is equivalent to `constructor() {super(); this._wheels = [];}` while being easier to read and easier to maintain.*

However, since the type of the elements of the `_wheels` array is passed to `Vehicle<TWheel>` when we extend it, we can improve the code further by writing removing the `abstract` modifier from `_wheels` in vehicle, implementing the array there and removing any need to define it in subclasses.

```
class Vehicle<TWheel extends Wheel> {
  _wheels: TWheel[] = [];
  wheels() {
    return this._wheels; // assume it's more complex than this
  }
}
```

And this simplifies `Car` to

`class Car extends Vehicle<CarWheel>{ }`

With `Car` parameterizing `Vehicle` with `CarWheel`, your original code now works.

```
car.wheels().forEach(wheel => wheel.hubcap);
```

The above now works because a `Car`'s wheels are known to be `CarWheel`

*Note: To maintain compatibility with existing code, and to allow vehicles that don't have specialized wheels to extend vehicle simply and concisely, we can specify a default for our type parameter. Thus, if say another class, say representing armored vehicles, doesn't use specialized wheels, we can just write `class Armor extends Vehicle { }`.*

```
class Vehicle<TWheel extends Wheel = Wheel> {
  _wheels: TWheel[] = [];
  wheels() {
    return this._wheels;
  }
}
```

Finally, let's touch up the `Vehicle` to make it more idiomatic. `wheels` doesn't need to be a method, we can use a `get` property accessor.

```
class Vehicle<TWheel extends Wheel = Wheel> {
  get wheels() { return this._wheels; }
}
```

This let's consumers write `car.wheels.forEach(...)` without thinking about the encapsulation technique ("oh this is a wrapper method") something they needn't worry their heads about.

**Putting it together:**

```
class Wheel {
  diameter = 30;
}

class Vehicle<TWheel extends Wheel = Wheel> {
  _wheels: TWheel[] = [];
  get wheels() {
    return this._wheels; // assume it's more complex than this
  }
}

class CarWheelHubcap {
  size = 15;
}

class CarWheel extends Wheel {
  hubcap = new CarWheelHubcap();
}

class Car extends Vehicle<CarWheel> {
  drivetrain: 'AWD' | 'FWD' | 'RWD' = 'AWD';
}

const car = new Car();

car.wheels
  .map(wheel => wheel.hubcap)
  .forEach(console.log);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqAWBTRJoG8CwAoa0AmAlmALaIAuiATtALzQDMADANzYC+22okMAaovAKhEAHgAqCZKkQAPCgDs8MSSlpwkKAHzpsuAPoB3DSAgAuaBOMBtALprbrHNADm5aEakQAFAEodT3EpyAFdKeWgyQQgAOkNjCGZoAHok6B5g0mgCMgByGGIAeyDoYALiAAcQWQj4MHDIgghdaA4sVq5wKGgAYTBKFRAACWCAI2Awcv9cCAIAL0Q1AEYAVkd2rG4u3v7jaFkFJXUpKeh4UfHJunlEAx6+geGxid81zg3OmG29uURFPgEhFURNsBtpME48JQCAA3ciUMAEeTmHIAQVgABEctAAD7QHIAMQxWNxOQASkS1Kiia8sFwCvIIGQSn01NdbtsXm9xpRoh4UE0nNFiM8+agaNpRdEzk9yj5mtEAGZFACiYGA8C8pQZBSq0RABWcPmYQA)

*Note that I've added a member to each class because empty classes are a poor practice that can lead to bugs and cause confusion and mayhem.*

Also, if we need a constructor that takes an array of wheels, parametric polymorphism solution continues to work well for use. We can simply add a constructor to `Vehicle` that takes the wheels, and all subclasses will expose an appropriately typed constructor requiring an array of the specified `TWheel`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you so much! Unrelated to the original question, but is there a solution to circular parametric polymorphism? For example, `Wheel` now has a `_vehicle` parent reference and uses `TVehicle` type param. (Modified playground link posted in the Q)

Comment: @Alex you can break the cycle with an `any` and it works as expected but it doesn't feel quite right and should probably be revised. A better solution would be to extract some kind of intermediate conditional type or something like that but I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcCcBcAsCm0C2B7aiA0oCWAzUBZRPAZ1AAMBeUANUXlwGMAbRS0AQwDsATKrQDqSRK059E+LpFawKuHqABGaBFgCwAKBCgA7qQDmiWAC4qAFQCeAB1I2u0LihPJQAcgsjEY96HhcFFygzLjQzLKOoJLSsrAAdJTabIEUDExsiAA8XqKsoIgAHrCI-BTeYlnpLOwAfKDCeVm8VrX1AN7aoKAA+np5ZOa5PqwA2gC6DaATANxdoMaw+gMAFACUoJ1a3d2YsDBKCLhk8X0DM6C6qZAueLDuFOiYIWgoNuyFRAGHTGTzAL7aQFaFJkcpNCzVTIFYqlPhpRg1bIVVj1WhQuqbebMNA8MiwaCQZiwDArGyQZSsFi9ABuiMyQwxiA27VAwOByVYqVAAGFHCiABIU5hcGybNnaTncvnQFEwkplUAorIyjqS7b+YWiqY8RB6Xn8vJC5QimzrOZaDkgrlgg3QeVwhEZdgqw0jWqsq04vFLEX22i6-Uy83qoA